# Call a method from other component when input value change in another component

Tags: angular

I have two component one is header and one is map component.I place input box in header and i want to call a method in map component when i change the input box value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of these methods:

- Using Event emitters by a parent component
- Create a service and inject it in the components
- Passing the component

You can more info here: [3 ways to communicate between Angular components](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb)

Comment: hi,but i m not using parent child relationship .both components are separate.

Comment: So you can use the second and the third option. Create a service or Passing the component